# In s:iterator tag im having set of hyperlinks which leads to respective datas. I need to know which link is clicked

Tags: struts2

In s:iterator tag I have set of hyperlinks which leads to respective data. I need to know which link is clicked

Here my code:

```
<s:iterator value="datasFinal" status="reportStatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="#reportStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">

<td align="center"><s:property value="#reportStatus.count" /></td>
<td align="center"><a href="javascript:submit('')">
<s:set name="index" value="#reportStatus.index" scope="session"/>
<s:property value="reportName" /> </a></td>
</tr>
<s:hidden name="reportName" value="%{reportName}"/>                                 
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: where you are setting hyperlinks?

Comment: Give each link a unique ID, index, etc. It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, thank u RAO and Dave.

```
<s:iterator value="datasFinal" status="reportStatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="#reportStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">

<td align="center"><s:property value="#reportStatus.count" /></td>
<td align="center"><a href="javascript:submit('${reportName}')">
<s:set name="index" value="#reportStatus.index" scope="session"/>
<s:property value="reportName" /> </a></td>
</tr>                               
</s:iterator>
```

By submitting this to java script i got which link is clicked...